# why the size of jumbotron(bootstrap)is changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using jumbotron to display time but as the time is changing the size of the box is also changing but I don't want that box to change when the time changes so what should I do so that the box will not change?

here is the code.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  
  <body onload="display_time();">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- This is going to create a jumbotron -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Current Date and Time:<span id="time"></span></h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <br><br>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class=" card card-body">
            <div class="container">
            <h2 id="indiatime"></h2><br>   
            <img src="india.png">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
              <h2 id="nepaltime"></h2><br>   
              <img src="javapic.png">
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function display_sec() {
        var refresh = 1000;
        time = setInterval('display_time()', refresh);
      }
      function display_time() {
        var a = new Date();
        let date = a.toLocaleString();
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = date;
        display_sec();
      }
    </script>
    <!---->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```